# Display items in child of child in column in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three css classes: .Home, .Products, and .Item.

basically all components on the .Home should display in a column like this:

```
Home
  Products
  Button
  Something else
```

While everything in .Products should display sequentially like this:

```
Products
  Item01  Item02  Item03 Item04
  Item05  Item06  Item07 Item...
```

However I have tried a lot and I cannot get this to be the desired output the items always display vertically or horizontally in different situations.

If I delete the products wraping div the items display in a column, but if I add a button I want it to display below all of the items and not with the item list like it is apart of the list.

if I add the wrapping div then the items always display in a row or like

```
A
B
C
D
```

```css
.Home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.Products {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.Item {
  margin-right: 3%;
  /* start: added by editor for visualization purpose */
  min-height: 75px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
  /* end: added by editor for visualization purpose */
}
```

```html
<div class="Home">
  <section class="Products">
    <div class="Item">1</div>
    <div class="Item">2</div>
    <div class="Item">3</div>
    <div class="Item">4</div>
    <div class="Item">5</div>
    <div class="Item">6</div>
    <div class="Item">7</div>
    <div class="Item">8</div>
  </section>
  <div>
    <button>Add Product</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

any help would be appreciated, I am stumped and have never had an issue like this with flexbox

Comment: please provide an actual HTML as [repro]. Unparsed react is not helpfull to replicate the issue you have and to tell you where the issue lies.

Comment: Ok well, is that good enough a lot is left out that is probably needed, but if that's all I can put then ok

Answer (score 0):

If you want your items to appear on multiple rows, then you would need to set `flex-wrap` to `wrap` and give each of your items a `flex-basis`, or `min-width`

```css
.Home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.Products {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100% !important;
  /* this height ruins the day */
  /* height: 100px; */
  color: white;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.Item {
  /* start: added by editor for visualization purpose */
  min-height: 75px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
  /* allow for margin, and borders */
  flex-basis:calc(25% - 3%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* end: added by editor for visualization purpose */
}
```

```html
<div class="Home">
  <section class="Products">
    <div class="Item">1</div>
    <div class="Item">2</div>
    <div class="Item">3</div>
    <div class="Item">4</div>
    <div class="Item">5</div>
    <div class="Item">6</div>
    <div class="Item">7</div>
    <div class="Item">8</div>
  </section>
  <div>
    <button>Add Product</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the width of the child items is off because you calculated them wrong. I would leave the border out of the calculation and use `border-box` instead. You calculate then still each child element with `25% - 3% = 22%`. If you take those times 4 you end up with `88% width`. Then we have `3 * 3% = 9%` for the gaps. If we add both we get a sum of `97% width` where you still miss `3%`. The correct caluclation is: `width: calc((100% - (3 * 3%)) / 4);`

Answer (score 0):

YOu where nearly there. You had to add `flex-wrap` to the parent and to calculate the correct width of the cards (item). See the comments within CSS for further reference:

```css
.Home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.Products {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: row; *//* default value and as such unecessary redundant */
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px; /* change to min-height to prevent overflow issues */
  color: white;
  --gap: 3%; /* variable for gap, required to calculate correct spacings */
  gap: var(--gap); /* includes the gap */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* to allow Item to wrap after 4 items to a new row */
}

.Item {
  /* margin-right: 3%; *//* poor use for spacings, use gap on the parent instead */
  /* start: added by editor for visualization purpose */
  min-height: 75px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* end: added by editor for visualization purpose */
  --col: 4; /* variable for ammount of columns to calculate correct width */
  width: calc((100% - ((var(--col) - 1) * var(--gap))) / var(--col)); /* calculates the correct width for the cards and taking the gap into account.
}
```

```html
<div class="Home">
  <section class="Products">
    <div class="Item">1</div>
    <div class="Item">2</div>
    <div class="Item">3</div>
    <div class="Item">4</div>
    <div class="Item">5</div>
    <div class="Item">6</div>
    <div class="Item">7</div>
    <div class="Item">8</div>
  </section>
  <div>
    <button>Add Product</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you touch the markup? And add a line break (after whatever flex item you want the line to break). Add `<div class="line-break"></div>` after the item you want link break, this css `.line-break {width: 100%; visibility: hidden;}` and a `flex-flow: row wrap;` to `.Products`

```css
.Home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.Products {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.Item {
  margin-right: 3%;
  /* start: added by editor for visualization purpose */
  min-height: 75px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
  /* end: added by editor for visualization purpose */
}

.line-break {
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="Home">
  <section class="Products">
    <div class="Item">1</div>
    <div class="Item">2</div>
    <div class="Item">3</div>
    <div class="Item">4</div>
    <div class="line-break"></div>
    <div class="Item">5</div>
    <div class="Item">6</div>
    <div class="Item">7</div>
    <div class="Item">8</div>
  </section>
  <div>
    <button>Add Product</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use `grid` which is always a go to approach for such kind of layouts.

```css
.Item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

.Products {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="Home">
  <section class="Products">
    <div class="Item">1</div>
    <div class="Item">2</div>
    <div class="Item">3</div>
    <div class="Item">4</div>
    <div class="Item">5</div>
    <div class="Item">6</div>
    <div class="Item">7</div>
    <div class="Item">8</div>
  </section>
  <div>
    <button>Add Product</button>
  </div>
</div>
```